# Byte[] to InputStream or OutputStream

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream, outputstream

I have a blob column in my database table, for which I have to use `byte[]` in my Java program as a mapping and to use this data I have to convert it to `InputStream` or `OutputStream`. But I don't know what happens internally when I do so. Can anyone briefly explain me what's happening when I do this conversion?

Comment: Shouldn't the title be "array of bytes ..." or "byte array..." or "byte[]..." instaed of "byte of array..."?

Comment: See the reverse here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You create and use byte array I/O streams as follows:

```
byte[] source = ...;
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(source);
// read bytes from bis ...

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// write bytes to bos ...
byte[] sink = bos.toByteArray();
```

Assuming that you are using a JDBC driver that implements the standard [JDBC Blob interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) (not all do), you can *also* connect a `InputStream` or `OutputStream` to a blob using the `getBinaryStream` and `setBinaryStream` methods<sup>1</sup>, and you can also get and set the bytes directly.

(In general, you should take appropriate steps to handle any exceptions, and close streams.  However, closing `bis` and `bos` in the example above is unnecessary, since they aren't associated with any external resources; e.g. file descriptors, sockets, database connections.)

<sup>1 - The `setBinaryStream` method is really a getter.  Go figure.</sup>

Answer (score 14):

I'm assuming you mean that 'use' means read, but what i'll explain for the read case can be basically reversed for the write case.

so you end up with a byte[]. this could represent any kind of data which may need special types of conversions (character, encrypted, etc). let's pretend you want to write this data as is to a file.

firstly you could create a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) which is basically a mechanism to supply the bytes to something in sequence.

then you could create a [FileOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) for the file you want to create. there are many types of InputStreams and OutputStreams for different data sources and destinations.

lastly you would write the InputStream to the OutputStream. in this case, the array of bytes would be sent in sequence to the FileOutputStream for writing. For this i recommend using [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)

```
byte[] bytes = ...;//
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(...));
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
```

and in reverse

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(...));
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
```

if you use the above code snippets you'll need to handle exceptions and i recommend you do the 'closes' in a finally block.

Comment: didnt you mean  - ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  instead ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayInputStream();

Comment: CloseQuietly should probably be in a finally clause.

Answer (score 5):

we can convert byte[] array into input stream by using ByteArrayInputStream

```
String str = "Welcome to awesome Java World";
    byte[] content = str.getBytes();
    int size = content.length;
    InputStream is = null;
    byte[] b = new byte[size];
    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
```

For full example please check here http://www.onlinecodegeek.com/2015/09/how-to-convert-byte-into-inputstream.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no conversion between InputStream/OutputStream and the bytes they are working with. They are made for binary data, and just read (or write) the bytes one by one as is.

A conversion needs to happen when you want to go from byte to char. Then you need to convert using a character set. This happens when you make String or Reader from bytes, which are made for character data.

Answer (score 2):

```
output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
...
input = new ByteArrayInputStream( output.toByteArray() )
```

Answer (score 0):

I do realize that my answer is way late for this question but I think the community would like [a newer approach to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481409/byte-array-of-unknown-length-in-java-part-ii/19144417#19144417).

Comment: Circular buffers do not solve the OP's problem.  In the Question as written, the OP needs the *entire* content in a single byte array.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] data = dbEntity.getBlobData();
response.getOutputStream().write();
```

I think this is better since you already have an existing OutputStream in the response object.
no need to create a new OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

```
String info = "somedata";       
OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("mydata.bin");
        byte [] datas= info.getBytes();
        os.write(datas);
    
InputStream is=new FileInputStream("mydata.bin");

        datas=new byte[1000];
        int counts = is.read(datas); //reads all data from bin to datas then returns size

        info = new String(datas,0,counts); //
        is.close();;


        System.out.println("From Binary File: " + info);
```