# Chunked http decoding in java?

Tags: java, http, chunked-encoding

I am decoding http packets. 
And I faced a problem that chunk problem.
When I get a http packet it has a header and body. 
When transefer-encoding is chunked I don't know what to do ?

Is there a useful API or class for dechunk the data in JAVA ?

And if someone , experienced about http decoding , please show me a way how to do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a fullworthy HTTP client like [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/) or just the Java SE provided [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) ([mini tutorial here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)). Both handles it fully transparently and gives you a "normal" `InputStream` back. HttpClient in turn also comes with a [`ChunkedInputStream`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/ChunkedInputStream.html) which you just have to decorate your `InputStream` with.

If you really insist in homegrowing a library for this, then I'd suggest to create a class like `ChunkedInputStream extends InputStream` and write logic accordingly. You can find more detail how to parse it in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Comment: Actually I make offline http decoding and I have just header and body of http packet. And I will decode the packet. But I need an api that gets header and body and gives me decoded data. 
Is there so api ?

Comment: The Wikipedia article contains detail how a chunk look like. You can basically just split on CRLF (\r\n). It are the bytes 10 and 13. The first part is then the header which represents the chunk length in hex. The second part is then the chunk data itself. You just collect and concatenate all those chunks. The `ChunkedInputStream` does exactly that.

Comment: Sorry , there are two ChunkedInputStream class
first: http://jigsaw.w3.org/Doc/Programmer/api/org/w3c/www/http/ChunkedInputStream.html

second: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/ChunkedInputStream.html

Which one is right for this ?
And Do you have any information about how to use ChunkedInputStream ?

Comment: The `ChunkedInputStream` part in my answer is clickable (as all other blueish parts). It's an `InputStream`, you can just decorate another `InputStream` with it. E.g. `InputStream input = new ChunkedInputStream(originalInput);`.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answers , they indeed help me. But I have an another question 
ChunkedInputStream constructor gets  SessionInputBuffer( interface )
How I will convert the string( chunked body ) to this format ?

Comment: Hmm, it has changed as per HttpClient 4.x. Well, either pick the HttpClient 3.x one which takes an `InputStream` or homebrew one. Detemining a chunked body is pretty trivial. Just split on CRLF and do the logic math.

Answer (score 1):

Apache [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)

Oh, and if we are talking about the client side, [HttpUrlConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) does this as well.

Comment: I will offline http decoding( already captured packets ) and I have just a header and a body.
So I need an api that gets just header and body and gives me decoded data. 
Is there any api like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple API try **Jodd Http** library (http://jodd.org/doc/http.html).
It handles Chunked transfer encoding for you and you get the whole body as a string back.

From the docs:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.get("http://jodd.org");
HttpResponse response = httpRequest.send();

System.out.println(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick-and-dirty alternative that requires no dependency except Oracle JRE:

```
private static byte[] unchunk(byte[] content) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
    ChunkedInputStream cis = new ChunkedInputStream(bais, new HttpClient() {}, null);
    return readFully(cis);
}
```

It uses the same `sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream` as `java.net.HttpURLConnection` does behind the scene.

This implementation doesn't provide detailed exceptions (line numbers) on wrong content format.

It works with Java 8 but could fail in with next release. You've been warned.

Could be useful for prototyping though.

You can choose any `readFully` implementation from [Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java).