# Consuming chunk encoded data using Apache HTTPComponents

Tags: java, encoding, chunked-encoding, apache-httpcomponents

Is there a helper method in HTTP Client that allows you to consume chunk encoded data whenever one chunk arrived on the wire?  Perhaps I overlooked this but I couldn't find anything related with this topic.  I did see this [Chunked http decoding in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717640/chunked-http-decoding-in-java) but that ChunkedInputStream is no longer available in HTTP Client 4.x

Here's what coming in over the wire.

```
HttpResponseHandlerImpl.setContentType(): application/json
HttpResponseHandlerImpl.setContentLength(): -1
58495 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "24[\r][\n]"
58495 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "{"firstName":"David","lastName":"0"}"
58495 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "[\r][\n]"
58495 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "24[\r][\n]"
58495 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "{"firstName":"David","lastName":"1"}"
58495 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "[\r][\n]"
58495 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "24[\r][\n]"
58495 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "{"firstName":"David","lastName":"2"}"
58501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "[\r][\n]"
58501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "0[\r][\n]"
58501 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - << "[\r][\n]"
```

What I want to do is to process a chunk at a time.  Is there any helper method that allows you to do this? or I just need to get the InputStream and do this manually?  Manually as in get the chunk size then read the buffer based on the chunk size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the idealistic solution since I was hoping to utilize the HttpComponents helper if any to parse chunk encoded data but I got this working using the Jackson's JsonParser http://jackson.codehaus.org/, and I know that the response returning back from my web service would always be JSON objects.

Here's the code

```
    try {

        MappingJsonFactory jsonFactory = new MappingJsonFactory();

        JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(inputStream);

        JsonToken token = null;

        token = jsonParser.nextToken();

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        do {

            if (token == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                buffer.append("{");
            } else if (token == JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                buffer.append("}");
                System.out.println("Received chunk: " + buffer.toString());
                buffer.setLength(0);
            } else if (token == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                jsonParser.nextToken();
                buffer.append("\"" + jsonParser.getCurrentName() + "\":");
                buffer.append("\"" + jsonParser.getText() + "\":");
            } else if (token == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
                buffer.append("\"" + jsonParser.getCurrentName() + "\":");
                buffer.append("\"" + jsonParser.getText() + "\":");
            }

            token = jsonParser.nextToken();

        } while (token != null);

    } catch (Throwable th) {
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
```