# How can I talk to nginx using plain HTTP/1.1 with pure Java sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, http, nginx

I connect a nginx http service by socket,i use java Language：

```
url：api.weibo.com/2/users/show.json

GET /2/users/show.json HTTP/1.1
Host: api.weibo.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: PHPSESSID=uc67dtcb5r3orchgv0dgdd0f57; think_template=default
```

but it return：

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Weibo
Date: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 10:07:33 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Api-Server-IP: 10.75.0.174
Vary: Accept-Encoding

60
{"error":"source paramter(appkey) is missing","error_code":10006,"request":"/2/users/show.json"}
0
```

i don't know what is the '60' and '0'

if i use HTTP/1.0 instand of HTTP/1.1,it return:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Weibo
Date: Sat, 24 Jan 2015 10:22:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Api-Server-IP: 10.75.5.92
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{"error":"source paramter(appkey) is missing","error_code":10006,"request":"/2/users/show.json"}
```

if i use socket connect iis or apache,all ok to use HTTP/1.1

Anybody can tell me why,and how to Solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chunked http decoding in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717640/chunked-http-decoding-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webservice returns the content in chunks, by first sending the length of the next chunk. It is using [Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1).

You are saying you can speak HTTP/1.1 with `GET /2/users/show.json HTTP/1.1` and

> All HTTP/1.1 applications MUST be able to receive and decode the
> "chunked" transfer-coding....

You could use something like the Apache HttpClient or some other Java HTTP client library to avoid implementing HTTP on your own.

Comment: thanks for your answer.i just study the http protocol,use socket can let me learn more. if the socket return 0,it mean i can close socket?and if use the "chunked",where i can see?or just do it myself?

Comment: If you read 0 from the socket/stream after a chunk while using chunked transfer encoding you could close the socket. If you meant the return value of the read call on the socket that returns 0 it does just mean that there is no data to read from the socket. It would return -1 if the connection got closed.