# How to assign a value to byte array

Tags: java, arrays

```
byte abc[]="204.29.207.217";
```

This is giving an error. Please, tell me correct the method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert InputStream to byte\[\] in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're trying to assign hard-coded values, you can use:

```
byte[] bytes = { (byte) 204, 29, (byte) 207, (byte) 217 };
```

Note the cast because Java bytes are signed - the cast here will basically force the overflow to a negative value, which is probably what you want.

If you're *actually* trying to parse a string, you need to do that - split the string into parts and parse each one.

If you're trying to convert a string into its binary representation under some particular encoding, you should use `String.getBytes`, e.g.

```
byte[] abc = "204.29.207.217".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

(Note that conventionally the `[]` is put as part of the type of the variable, not after the variable name. While the latter is allowed, it's discouraged as a matter of style.)

Comment: Will `(byte) 128` result in `-1`? I'm always confused with it. I know it will work in C++ (except we have to use `char` instead of `byte`), but I wasn't sure about Java.

Comment: @Martijn: No, `(byte) 128` will result in -128. `(byte) 255` will result in -1.

Comment: @Martijn `byte` is an 8-bit signed integer in Java, it's range goes from -128 to +127. It's stored in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format.

Comment: Oh, yes indeed! I meant indeed `(byte) 255`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That's a *string literal*. If you're looking to get the binary representation of the string, use one of the `String.getBytes` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Either use char[] or String.  Make sure and get the includes for String.