# IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed - How to resolve?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serverAdress + "/rootservices");
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet, localContext);

        String projectURL = XMLDocumentParser.parseDocument(response.getEntity().getContent(), "oslc_scm:scmServiceProviders", "rdf:resource");
        String workItemURL = XMLDocumentParser.parseDocument(response.getEntity().getContent(), "oslc_cm:cmServiceProviders", "rdf:resource");
```

The problem here is that I read two times the HttpResponse object. So the second time I get the exception. But although I know the problem, I can´t find an easy solution. So what is a good way to solve that problem?

Comment: Is this apache's `HttpClient`? If so, I'm surprised that the content isn't cached. That seems like a really poor design choice on their part..as you can see, it obviously gives users of their API lots of unnecessary grief.

Comment: @mre the same behavior occurs with Jersey Client.

Comment: @Matt Ball, Interesting. Is there reasoning behind the madness?

Comment: Not really. The most information I ever found on it: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-162. It's certainly idiomatic Java to not be able to read an input stream more than once, so I can kind of see how it might make sense. Still sucks for `HttpResponse`/`ClientResponse`, though.

Comment: @Matt Ball, "Resolution: Won't Fix" ... "Priority: Major". Wow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the input stream returned by `response.getEntity().getContent()` into a `byte[]`, stored in a local variable. See [Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java).

```
byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity().getContent());

String projectURL = XMLDocumentParser.parseDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(content), "oslc_scm:scmServiceProviders", "rdf:resource");
String workItemURL = XMLDocumentParser.parseDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(content), "oslc_cm:cmServiceProviders", "rdf:resource");
```

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't have to parse the entire document twice, though. What API provides `XMLDocumentParser#parseDocument()`?

Answer (score 1):

Read the response content only once, and copy it to some kind of buffer compatible with `XMLDocumentParser.parseDocument`. Then parse the data directly from your buffer, as many times as you want.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try it this way?

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serverAdress + "/rootservices");
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
        InputStream in = null;
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet, localContext);

        in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String projectURL = XMLDocumentParser.parseDocument(in, "oslc_scm:scmServiceProviders", "rdf:resource");
        String workItemURL = XMLDocumentParser.parseDocument(in, "oslc_cm:cmServiceProviders", "rdf:resource");
```