# How to insert uploaded image from p:fileUpload as BLOB in MySQL?

Tags: jsf, jpa, file-upload, primefaces

How to insert uploaded image from p:fileUpload as BLOB in MySQL?

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "photo")
private byte[] photo;
```

And in XHTML page, I write [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml):

```
<p:inputText value="#{condidat.condidat.photo}" >
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"   
    allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;" description="Images"/>                       
</p:inputText>
```

How can I retreive the value of uploaded file as `byte[]`?

Comment: An Error Occurred:

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.

Comment: You have to play with the StreamedContent received from the fileUpload component. You have an example in the showcase. What version of PF do you use? Once you have the streamedContent, you can insert it in DB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the uploaded file content via `FileUploadEvent`. In PrimeFaces 4.x with Apache Commons FileUpload, or in PrimeFaces 5.x with context param `primefaces.UPLOADER` set to `commons`, you can use `UploadedFile#getContents()` to obtain the uploaded file as `byte[]`.

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    byte[] content = event.getFile().getContents();
    // ...
}
```

In PrimeFaces 5.x with context param `primefaces.UPLOADER` absent or set to `auto` or `native` while using JSF 2.2, then `getContents()` will return `null` as that's [not implemented in `NativeUploadedFile` implementation](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5.1.x/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/NativeUploadedFile.java). Use `UploadedFile#getInputStream()` instead and then [read bytes from it, e.g. with help of commons IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java).

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(event.getFile().getInputstream());
    // ...
}
```

Finally, just set this `byte[]` in your entity and persist/merge it.

Make sure that you have set the form encoding type to `multipart/form-data` and, when using the Apache Commons FileUpload, that you have configured the [file upload filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083) in `web.xml` as per PrimeFaces user guide.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to mention that, I had to use:

```
public void handleUpload(FileUploadEvent e) throws Exception {
    byte[] contents = IOUtils.toByteArray(e.getFile().getInputstream());
    //....
}
```

As it seems that in PrimeFaces 5.x, the `getContents()` always returns null !