# Handle varbinary file to download, upload, and display? Primefaces 3.4 - fileupload - filedownload - media

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, download, media, varbinary

I use Glassfish 3.1.2.2, Sql Server 2005, PF 3.4 and Mojarra 2.1.6. Ide Eclipse Juno.

I use stored procedure, and add jar commons-io.1.4 and commons-fileupload.1.2.1

**In database, we save all file (pdf, doc, xls, etc.) in varbinary.**
I have these doubts:

1. How I can upload any **file (pdf, doc, xls, etc.)** with **p:fileupload** and save as **varbinary** file in the **database**?
2. How I can download any **varbinary** file of **database** with **p:FileDownload**?
3. How I can show pdf with **p:media**, recovering files **varbinary** from the **database**?

**ONE QUESTION**

How I can upload any file (pdf, doc, xls, etc.) with p: fileupload and save them to the database?

I undestood the p:fileupload, since documentation. 
I use this method, handlerFileUpload, for upload a file. Firsts get the inputScream of the event

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload}" />

public class FileBean {
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
       UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
       //application code
    }
}
```

I used file.getInputStream and sent the stored procedure a BinaryStream
setBinaryStream(4, inputStream, (int)inputStream.toString().getBytes().length);

This is good??

**TWO QUESTION**

How I can download any **varbinary** file  with **p:FileDownload**?

I recover a varbinary since database with getBytes.
Remember I use the stored procedure.

This method is in a class with request scope.

```
   public byte[] ArchivoBin(int CDTPEnlaceImagen, int iddoc) {
  Context();
  Null_Rs_and_Proc();
  Connection(0);
  PA(2, 51);

  [b]byte[] file = null;[/b]

  try {
     setProc(getCon().prepareCall(getCall()));
     getProc().setInt(1, CDTPEnlaceImagen);
     getProc().setInt(2, iddoc);

     setRs(getProc().executeQuery());
     getRs().next();

     [b]file = getRs().getBytes(1);[/b]
     System.out.println(file);
  }
  catch(SQLException e) {
     System.out.println("Exception ArchivoBin");
     System.out.println(e);
  }
  CloseConnections();

  return file;}
```

But, when i get the file in bytes, i convert a bytes to inputscream, and then inputscream to DefaultStreamedContent.

This part is a class with request scope.

```
byte[] bytes = null;
bytes = getRecuperarDatos().ArchivoBin(
               1, 
               idarchivo);

//Archivo is a Session Scope
getArchivo().setFile(new DefaultStreamedContent(
                  [b]new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)[/b], 
                  "application/pdf", 
                  nomArchivo));
```

The **f:download** not get the file correct, It is corrupt.

```
<h:commandButton value="Download">
           [b]<p:fileDownload value="#{archivo.file}"[/b] />
        </h:commandButton>
```

I don't know why this bad

**THREE QUESTION**

How I can show pdf with **p:media**, recovering **varbinary files  from the database**?

This is similar to TWO QUESTION, p:media say 
"An error has occurred while loading the PDF document"

Comment: You shouldn't store files in a database that can be large. Instead store the file on disk and store the location of the file in the database. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211895/) for a pro/con.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is solved, when i save the file in database with the method contents.
Specifically, with

```
public void SubirAlBaseDatos(FileUploadEvent e) {
  bytes[] file = e.getFile().getContents();

);
```

thus, I can show in p:media, and donwload in p:filedownload.
Something insignificant was causing the problem.

Thank!! BalusC for your tips
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310773/1303201)