# PDFRenderer - Export to image, exported inaccurately

Tags: java

I have a program written to export PDF file to a series of images, it is shown as follow:

```
 //Load pdf from path(file)
    File file = new File("C:\\TEMP\\office\\a.pdf");
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    byte[] b = new byte[(int) raf.length()];
    raf.readFully(b);
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
    PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);



    //Get number of pages

    int numOfPages = pdffile.getNumPages();
    System.out.println(numOfPages);
    //iterate through the number of pages
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfPages; i++) {
        PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(i);
        //Create new image
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) page.getBBox().getWidth(), (int) page.getBBox().getHeight());
        Image img = page.getImage(rect.width, rect.height, rect, null, true, true);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(rect.width, rect.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        File asd = new File("C:\\TEMP\\office\\img\\Testingx" + i + ".jpg");
        if (asd.exists()) {
            asd.delete();
        }
//Export the image to jpg format using the path C:\TEMP\office\img\filename
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", asd);
    }
//Close the buf and other stuffs, which does not affect the image exported
```

This program works fine in lots of PDF files, however, while I was testing my program using various pdf found on the internet, there is a pdf that cannot be exported to image accurately like the others, the resources I used are listed below.

Original PDF Link: 
[2007_OReilly_EssentialActionScript3.0.pdf](http://bookshelf.theopensourcelibrary.org/2007_OReilly_EssentialActionScript3.0.pdf)

I will use the page 7 of the PDF given above.

The expected image to be export : [Click here for expected result image](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/7243/50lr.png)

After the program finished the operation, the resulting image is quite different.

[Click here for Resulting image](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/8420/m83x.jpg)

As you can see, the resulting image shifts upward and some of the content disappeared, the result image lost the formatting in the pdf, it is not centered, it indents itself to the right.

PDFrenderer itself does not have problem, if we run the .jar file of PDFrenderer , the top side and the formatting is consistent with the original PDF file.

[PDF opened with PDFRenderer in page 7](http://imageshack.com/a/img844/1185/xkyu.png)

Known possibly issue: ImageIO does not support CMYK format, thus, page 1 and other pages involves the use of CMYK format will be unable to be exported correctly. Not sure if I am right.

Another issue: PDFRenderer seems to be failed at reading page 1 which is possibly due to something used in the PDF formatting, I don't know much about it

Used library : [PDFRenderer](https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer)

You may download the PDF from the link aforementioned and use the program I provided to reproduce the problem.

My question: How can I fix this problem? Is there somethings wrong with my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself and I am be able to have it fixed.

The explanation as follow

My JAVA program does not follow the "X" coordinates and "Y" coordinates in pdf file, to be simple, my program hardcoded the X,Y coordinates. In most case, most pdf will be work like the following image

[Most PDF http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7618/4cl5.png](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7618/4cl5.png)

HOWEVER, the pdf I provided is not that case, the X coordinate of upper left corner is not 0 , so as the Y. that's why the image has been cut off.

To be short, my program will capture the PDF screen with a shape of rectangle, however since the PDF i provided above does not find the coordinate of upper left corner, so it will capture the screen like the image below. The Y Coordinates is not written in the picture, my mistake.

[Exception PDF http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/9672/plhb.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/9672/plhb.png)

With the following modification to the program, it will work like the most case and it is even more better.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)page.getPageBox().getX(), (int)page.getPageBox().getY(), (int) page.getBBox().getWidth(), (int) page.getBBox().getHeight());
```

This allows the program "capture" the entire pdf provided by PDFRenderer starting from upper left corner which is just like the first image I have provided, It will works the same even in different page size from A4 to A7, I didn't test further, but it works

Comment: many thanks to you for this Q & A style post. It was exactly what I needed

Comment: I only wonder... is it necessary for both BufferedImage **and** image? Maybe it's just the quirks of `java.awt` but the code with Rectangle, Image, BufferedImage, and Graphics seems odd