# Display image with base64 String in html?

Tags: java, html, image, base64

here is my java code that construct the base64 String from image. Then place the base64 String html, to view
the constructed image, but image  is not constructed somehow

```
public void getBase64String() throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream itStrm = new FileInputStream(
    "E:\\image\\56255254-flower.jpg");//image is lying at http://danny.oz.au/travel/mongolia/p/56255254-flower.jpg
    String str = itStrm.toString();
    byte[] b3 = str.getBytes();
    String base64String = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(b3);
    //output of base64String is amF2YS5pby5GaWxlSW5wdXRTdHJlYW1AMTdlMDYwMA==
  }
```

**Now in html page i placed the output of base64String in img tag to view the image.But image does not shows up
(instead it display the cross image icon). I am not getting image is not displayed from base64 String below?**

```
      <HTML>
      <BODY>
           <img    src="data:image/jpeg;base64,amF2YS5pby5GaWxlSW5wdXRTdHJlYW1AMTdlMDYwMA=="/>

     </BODY>
     </HTML>
```

**EDIT:-** Thanks Folks, i used byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);. It worked for me!!

Comment: That's an awfully small string for such a huge image.

Comment: Blenedr, Is Base64String is not constructed correctly?

Comment: I got a wall of text. The base64 representation should take up more space than the actual image.

Comment: Also you might be better off using apache commons library.http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: `String base64String = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(b3);`  Look to [`DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) in a more modern JRE, and the [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#method_summary) centered around `Base64`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This: `String str = itStrm.toString()` is not the image but the `toString()` representation of the `FileInputStream` instance.

You'll have to read the bytes from the stream and store them in a byte array. And, for performance reasons, buffer the stream:

```
BufferedInputStream itStrm = new BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(
    "E:\\image\\56255254-flower.jpg"));
```

**Further reading (Spoiler: solution inside)**

- [Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java)

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I used byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is); it worked for me. I have one more related question. I need to send the image with email body which can be sent to no email server like gmail,yahoo etc. I was planning to convert it to base64string first and then make the image tag out of it and store it with body. Now wherever the email body goes, base64 string will be displayed as image.To me it looks good solution. But i am not sure is there any downside of it?

Comment: Good to hear that it works now. Please make a new post for the other question :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the `read()` method of the `FileInputStream` instance instead of the `toString()` to get the content of the image. Then you are able to encode it and should work as you expected.

Something like:

```
int c;
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("");
while((c = fileInputStream.read()) != -1)
{
    result .append((char)c);
}
```