# How to download s3 object directly into memory in java

Tags: amazon-s3, task

Is it possible to download `S3object` in `Java` directly into memory and get it removed when i'm done with  the task?

Answer (score 58):

Use the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) and [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) as such:

```java
//import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

AmazonS3 s3  = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);  // anonymous credentials are possible if this isn't your bucket
S3Object object = s3.getObject("bucket", "key"); 
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
```

Not sure what you mean by "get it removed", but `IOUtils` will close the object's input stream when it's done converting it to a byte array.  If you mean you want to delete the object from s3, that's as easy as:

```java
s3.deleteObject("bucket", "key");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!this would require the use of additional libraries. Wouldn't it be better if i loop through input stream to get the byte array?

Comment: @Manisha, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java.

Comment: You can now do this without `org.apache.commons.io`. The AWS SDK ships this method in it's own IOUtils: `import com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils;`

Answer (score 7):

As of AWS JAVA SDK 2 you can you use `ReponseTransformer` to convert the response to different types. (See [javadoc](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#getObject-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest-software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.ResponseTransformer-)).

Below is the example for getting the object as bytes

```
GetObjectRequest request = GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build()
ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> result = bytess3Client.getObject(request, ResponseTransformer.toBytes())

// to get the bytes
result.asByteArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, convert file data to string:

```
S3Object s3object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();
StreamUtils.copyToString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best practise.

```
S3Object object = s3.getObject("bucket", "key"); 
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
```