# PDF files not opening using class loader

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am using the below code to link files to resources folder and reading the file and writing, and then i am opening the pdf file via 3rd party app.

This is my code;

```
public void readFile(){
        InputStream fileInputStream= null;
        String filePath = "PDF/" + name + ".pdf";
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        try {
             fileInputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
             int size = fileInputStream.available();
             byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
             fileInputStream.read(buffer);
             fileInputStream.close();

             writeFile(buffer, name);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeFile( byte[] buffer, String fileName){
        try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

            if (root.canWrite()){
                File pdffile = new File("/sdcard/aaa/bbb");
                pdffile.mkdirs();
                System.out.println(" pdf path "+pdffile.toString());
                File outputFile = new File(pdffile.toString());
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        outputFile+"/" + fileName + ".pdf");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        fileOutputStream);
                bos.write(buffer);
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Rrror", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

File f = new File("/sdcard/aaa/bbb/"+name+".pdf");
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(f);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
```

Now some files it reading and opening properly but few files its not opening it says K

`"This Document cannot be opened".`

But if i use assest manager to open the files it works perfectly fine.

what is problem here,

Comment: Did you check the version of your file located in "/sdcard/aaa/bbb/"? Or only in the resources? If you check and compare them, and they differ, that may be due to you assuming that `InputStream.available()` returns the correct size of underlying resource: it only contains *an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.* (according to the JDK JavaDocs)

Comment: @mkl thnaks, yes your are correct, the file size differs  what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sizes of the resource and the extracted copy in "/sdcard/aaa/bbb" differ. This is due to the false assumption that `InputStream.available()` returns the correct size of underlying resource: it only contains *an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream* (according to the JDK JavaDocs).

Thus you have to change the code that copies the input stream to the byte array. This subject has been discussed on StackOverflow before, e.g. cf. [Convert InputStream to byte[] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java) (only regard the answers that ignore the fact that that question refers to an image file, e.g. the one by @RichSeller using Apache commons-io or, without introducing new dependencies, the one by @Adamski using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, a `byte[]` buffer, and a loop copying while not at end-of-file (`is.read(...) != -1`). There might also be niftier `nio` solutions, but what the heck... ;)

Comment: can you please help me which one to add in my case? i am confused?

Comment: If your project already has a dependency on Apache commons-io, try @RichSeller's `IOUtils.toByteArray(is)`; otherwise use @Adamski's `ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = ...; while(...) {...} ... buffer.toByteArray();`

Comment: ok i am trying with @Adamski's soultion, please wait, but what is this number 16384

Comment: 16384 is simply 16*1024, i.e. 16K --- when working with such buffers there is the assumption that buffer lengths of some multiple of 1 KB are more efficient than other sizes. I'm not sure that still is true, but it does not hurt, either. Depending on the memory footprint of your application you may want a smaller buffer size, though, e.g. 8*1024.

Comment: ok if the file size is more than that buffer then it will not work right? what if i make that to 20000, My max PDF file size is 800kb

Comment: If the size of the file is larger than that of the buffer, the loop does enough iterations to copy all data piece by piece. If the size of the buffer is smaller than that of the file (or the last piece in multiple loop iterations), the actual number of bytes read is transported in `nRead`.

Comment: U mean even the buffer size is less than 800k then also the pdf file wll be rendered?

Comment: and can you help on how to read the pdf files within app? i have tried with PDFViewer but it will work sometimes and do not work some times

Comment: This buffer is used only for copying the file from your resources to sdcard. And for that job the buffer size will do. You could even use a 1 byte buffer but that would slow down everything. All I can help with is trying to copy the PDF correctly, though, I don't know about PDFViewer etc.

Comment: I will explain , currently i am reading the pdf from 3rd party app, instead i want to read the pdf files from my app? is there any lib,

Comment: According to your initial question you are *opening the pdf file via 3rd party app* and now you say you are *reading the pdf from 3rd party app* --- which way around is it? But that being said, I am not really into Android programming, I'm more a Java guy peeking into the Android world. Thus, you might want to ask a separate question on your new issue, *to read the pdf files from* your *app.*

Comment: ok any ways thanks, if you can share your email id (if your willing) please share i am not much experienced, so i can seek your help.