# Error opening tmp PDF from my Java application when run from JAR but not Eclipse

Tags: java, pdf, jar, embedded-resource

I want to be able to open a PDF file when the user clicks on 'HELP' in my application.  The PDF file is located with the JAR, extracted to a tmp directory and then selected to open by awt.Desktop.getDesktop () (to allow for windows and linux use).

When I run the app from Eclipse then it works fine, the PDF opens with no errors.  When I export to JAR and run then I get an error stating the 'PDF document is damaged', if I navigate  manually to the PDF document (on my ubuntu machine /tmp/546434564.pdf) then I get the same error when I try to open the file.  I am confused what is going on.  The file size of the 'damaged' PDF is the same as the working one, so I dont think it is a permission issue.

The code I am using is:

```
public Main() throws FontFormatException, IOException {

    //lets load the font
       Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Coalition_v2.ttf")).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 14); 
       System.out.println(font);

    //lets write the tmp file for help to the machine now
       try {
            java.io.InputStream iss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/nullpdf.pdf"); //update the filename here when the help guide is written
            byte[] data = new byte[iss.available()];
            iss.read(data);
            iss.close();
            String tempFile = "file";
            File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        tmphelpfile = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(tmphelpfile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("TEMP FILE NOT CREATED - ERROR in tmp file writing");
        }
```

And then to call the pdf:

```
JMenu mnHelpGuide = new JMenu("Help Guide");
mnHelpGuide.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    //  Help();
        Desktop d = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop ();  

        try {
            System.out.println(tmphelpfile);
            d.open (new java.io.File (String.valueOf(tmphelpfile)));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Couldnt open your file - error on HELP Guide");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    });
```

Comment: `iss.available()` does **not** necessary return the size of of the source resource. When run from eclipse, the resource already is in the file system, and file streams seem to return the file size here. When run from the jar, though, the jar resources stream returns something less. Thus, you should use a proper stream copying routine which often involves a loop until an end of the stream is signaled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Im new to Java so I would need a bit more leading through your suggested solution.  What better stream should I use to write out the tmp file?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933768/pdf-files-not-opening-using-class-loader/14935286#14935286

Comment: Thank you, sorted as detailed below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys.  The problem was fixed by importing the ApachecommonsIO jar and then modifying the code to this:

```
 try {
                java.io.InputStream iss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/nullpdf.pdf"); //update the filename here when the help guide is written
               // byte[] data = new byte[iss.available()];
                byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(iss);
                iss.read(data);
                iss.close();
                String tempFile = "file";
                File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            tmphelpfile = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(tmphelpfile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("TEMP FILE NOT CREATED - ERROR in tmp file writing");
            }
```