# File is not reading/creating properly when running outside Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, file, file-io, inputstream, outputstream

I searched and found many answer and I tried. Following is one of them:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder/SMSCApplication.pdf");
            System.out.println("reading file path ");
            byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(data);
            is.close();
            String tempFile = "User_Guide";
            File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(temp);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("NO PDF READER INSTALLED");
        }
    }
```

I run application with Netbeans IDE it is working fine. But when I run outside Netbeans it is not working. File creates on `temp` folder but corrupted (**When I try to open using my default `pdf` reader**).

**My question is, "how to make workable like inside netbeans if I run application form outside netbeans also" ?**

**Note :** My `pdf` file is inside `package` because if I distribute  my application no need to give `user_guide` file seperately

**Updated:**

[image: file directory]

Comment: Did you check content of `data` after reading it?

Comment: When I run from netbeans and I can read file but when I run outside netbeans I can not read it says `file is corrupted`. But I can read **txt** file from outside netbeans also. I can not read `doc` and `pdf`

Comment: You are not reading resource correctly. What if you do not read all data at once? Maybe in Netbeans data are read always at once, but in other environments they are not!

Comment: @Piro Please see my image where is complete directory.

Comment: It doesn't matter where data are if they are not read all! Find some tutorial on reading data. You should read data in while loop. Also you should close resources in finally block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for your support. Finally I found the solution from [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382377/error-opening-tmp-pdf-from-my-java-application-when-run-from-jar-but-not-elipse). I used third party [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library and changed code `byte[] data = new byte(iss.available());` to `byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(iss);`
and worked. Thanks to [**andy**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796209/andy)

```
try {
        InputStream iss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder/SMSCApplication.pdf"); //update the filename here when the help guide is written
        byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(iss);
        iss.read(data);
        iss.close();
        String tempFile = "User_Guide";
        File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        logger.error(temp.getAbsolutePath());
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(temp.getAbsoluteFile());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error(ex);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your filepath wrong.

You should be checking if InputStream is null.

`if(is == null) System.out.println("Couldn't open");`

Use Fully qualified paths.

Comment: Use fully qualified paths is not a solution. What if user want to build a jar and want to run the same jar on different environment say Mac, Windows and Linux. That's why fully qualified path is not a good idea.