# HtmlUnit use WebClient to download an image as base64 encoded DATA Uri

Tags: java, base64, htmlunit, data-uri

I want to use an existing instance of `WebClient` to download an image. The reason for this is because I want the cookies to be passed with the request.

How can I download an image using an existing instance of `WebClient`?

Also, how can I base64 encode the image to be able to view it using `data:image/jpeg;base64,...`

Current code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
UnexpectedPage imagePage = client.getPage("http://...");
String imageString = imagePage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String base64data = encoder.encode(imageString.getBytes());
```

So now I have base64 data of the image, but I still can't view the image using `data:image/jpeg;base64,...`.

Comment: How are you doing it now? I mean, how the existing instance `WebClient` is built (the code you are using)?

Comment: just assume the basic `WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);`

Comment: You have the image as string, do you want it as file?

Comment: i think i could find the code to convert it into file, but im interested in creating a base64 string that i could view in a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to consider:

- The `BASE64Encoder()` generates a string that has a line break every 77 chars. Take that out using `.replaceAll("\r?\n","")`.
- For that method also, it is better to retrieve the web page `InputStream` rather than the string. Also, to convert that to a `byte` array, I used a utility method (source and other options can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1264737/1850609)).

Working source code:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
    UnexpectedPage imagePage = client.getPage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DdHc.jpg");
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    String base64data = encoder.encode(inputStreamToByteArray(imagePage.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream()));
    System.out.println("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"+base64data.replaceAll("\r?\n","")+"\" />");
}

private static byte[] inputStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
    while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }
    buffer.flush();
    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Source image:

[image: yao face]

Output base64 image **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/JeayD/)**.

Comment: `imagePage.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()` does not work because it tries to encode the received content as `String`, and for that it changes to `?` the bytes it can't encode. Even using `getContentAsString("base64")` changes a byte here and there, witch can completely mess the image: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/JeayD/2/

Comment: yes, i figured that out. i used `image.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream()` and it worked