# How to convert Part to Blob, so I can store it in MySQL?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, blob

How to convert Part to Blob, so I can store it in MySQL? It is an image.
Thank you

My form

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:messages/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="File:"/>
            <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{uploadPage.uploadedFile}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:commandButton value="Upload File" action="#{uploadPage.uploadFile}"/>
</h:form>
```

My bean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UploadPage {       
    private Part uploadedFile; 

    public void uploadFile(){
    }
}
```

Comment: see the following  link about how to save blob image in database  http://jsfspotlight.blogspot.com/2013/09/ejb3jsf2primfacesuploading-and.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SQL database BLOB type is in Java represented as `byte[]`. This is in JPA further to be annotated as `@Lob`. So, your model basically need to look like this:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    @Lob
    private byte[] image;

    // ...
}
```

As to dealing with `Part`, you thus basically need to read its `InputStream` into a `byte[]`. You can use [`InputStream#readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--) for this:

```
InputStream input = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
byte[] image = input.readAllBytes();
someEntity.setImage(image);
// ...
entityManager.persist(someEntity);
```

Or if you're not on Java 9 yet, then head to [Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java) for alternative ways to read an `InputStream` into a `byte[]`.

Comment: I downloaded the library from http://apache.igor.onlinedirect.bg//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.4-bin.zip, and loaded the jar file in my project. I imported it like this `import org.apache.commons.io.*;`, but it tells me that it could not find it.....

Comment: Just drop JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Do not fiddle around in project's properties, for sure not *Build Path* and likes. If you did it before, make sure that you undo it all. By the way, I edited my answer to show the standard Java API approach.