# Getting full URL of an uploaded file deployed in local server in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have used p:fileUpload to upload an image. I don't really need to upload the image to the server but I just need to get the full local URL(ie.c:/.../../..) of the file(image) which is saved in the local disk, I tried but I just got the filename with the extension. This is an web application which is used locally, so both sever and client are on the same machine. The URL need to be saved in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons, browsers don't send the full client side file path. They only send the file contents and the file name. Ancient browsers and MSIE are the only browsers who expose the security bug of still sending the full client side file path along with the file upload. You should not be relying on this security bug in your application.

You're supposed to grab the file contents in flavor of `InputStream` of `byte[]` and write it **immediately** to a more permanent storage location yourself by `FileOutputStream` or perhaps via a `@Lob` to a `BLOB` column in DB. You can if necessary use `File#createTempFile()` to autogenerate an unique filename.

Note that a local disk file sytem path can't represent a valid HTTP URL which the client could use to obtain the file. Browsers like Firefox refuse to serve `file://` URLs when the initial webpage itself is opened by `http://` instead of `file://`. So you really need to serve those uploaded files back via a web server. It's recommended to just store only the file name (not full path!) in the DB. You can then configure the webserver to publish a certain folder to the web, or create a simple servlet to serve a certain folder to the web.

#### See also:

- [How to save uploaded file in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file/14214223#14214223)
- [How to convert Part to Blob, so I can store it in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138706/how-to-convert-part-to-blob-so-i-can-store-it-in-mysql/19139125#19139125)
- [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf/4543951#4543951)

Comment: Thanks for help. I found similar answers also. I appreciate your suggestion but I just needed to get the path. I have told my seniors about this. I have convinced about just saving the file name.