# Where can I upload files that can be accessed by Tomcat?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, file-upload

I am running a Java J2EE app in Tomcat and I would like to upload some files that can be directly served by Tomcat via URL (ie, I don't want to create an additional servlet to serve the files and I don't want to use Apache).

What is the solution to this? I know I should not create files inside the deployed WAR directory (if it is extracted at all), as illustrated in [this very old post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/570366/Tomcat/create-file-tomcat).

I tried creating another directory under "webapps":

```
System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "/webapps/uploadedFiles/";
```

but Tomcat does not seem to serve any file at "`localhost:8080/uploadedFiles/...`". So I had to put the files inside the webapps/ROOT directory, were they could be accessed. However, this looks ugly and it's probably not really correct, because I think the ROOT directory is not designed for such purposes.

My question is:

**HOW CAN I MAKE TOMCAT SERVE my upload files, considering that they cannot be placed in the deployed directory because they can be overwritten?**

Or, what is the same: where should I place my upload files so Tomcat can serve them directly via HTTP request and they don't get overwritten by redeployment?

Comment: I personally like to define a place for them completely outside tomcat and configure Apache to send requests directly to this directory, but because your answer doesn't mention Apache or deployment specific configurations i write this as a comment. But this would be one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. As you mention, I am not using Apache, only Tomcat

Comment: This is not opinion-based at all ...

Comment: I am sorry but I am not asking for opinion (e.g. if you like to place upload files inside a deployed WAR or in a directory called "my_files"), I am asking HOW can I make Tomcat to serve directly the files I upload (which cannot be in the WAR directory because they can get overwritten).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Saving uploaded file (don't use `getRealPath()` nor `part.write()`!)
>
> Head to the following answers for detail on properly saving the
>   obtained `InputStream` (the `fileContent` variable as shown in the
>   above code snippets) to disk or database:
>
> - [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-files-uploaded-to-a-tomcat-servlet/18664715#18664715)
> - [How to upload an image and save it in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033676/how-to-upload-an-image-and-save-it-in-database/7033945#7033945)
> - [How to convert Part to Blob, so I can store it in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138706/how-to-convert-part-to-blob-so-i-can-store-it-in-mysql/19139125#19139125)
>
> ### Serving uploaded file
>
> Head to the following answers for detail on properly serving the saved
>   file from disk or database back to the client:
>
> - [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi/4543951#4543951)
> - [How to retrieve and display images from a database in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340406/how-to-retrieve-and-display-images-from-a-database-in-a-jsp-page/2341322#2341322)
> - [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java/1812356#1812356)
> - [Servlet for serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content/29991447#29991447)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)