# Uploading images using Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, image, tomcat, servlets, upload

I have a simple form with enctype "multipart"; I am using this to upload an image to my server. I have two possible solutions, but neither of them are complete.

First solution:

```
FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator( request );

while( iterator.hasNext() ){
    FileItemStream item = iterator.next();

    if( item.isFormField() ){
          // store IMG
    }

} // ~while( iter.hasNext() )
```

In this solution, I can't get the dimensions of the uploaded file, but I can get if it's a form field or not (using `item.isFormField()`)

My second solution uses the Servlet 3.0 API:

```
for( Part part: request.getParts() ){
    System.out.println( part.getSize() );
}
```

Here I can get the size of the uploaded image, but I can't tell whether it's a simple form field or not.

What am I missing?

**What you need for help me?**

Comment: please tell me what you mean by dimensions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation of the [FileItemStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemStream.html)

the [isFormField()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemStream.html#isFormField%28%29) method tells whether if this is a simple form field returns true , otherwise return false .

so for upload image it will return false

so you should do the following :

```
  if(! item.isFormField() ){
              // store IMG
        }else {

//simple form field.
       }
```

and refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java/1264737#1264737) to see how to convert an InputStream to byte[] to know how many bytes are there in your uploaded file .

if you are using servlet 3 do like the following :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username= request.getParameter("username"); // Retrieves <input type="text" name="username">
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); // Retrieves <input type="file" name="file">
    String filename = filePart.getName();
    InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();
    // ... (do your job here)
}
```

and give me some feedback .

Hope that helps .

Comment: Oh good, Thanks for your response I will try!... There are any way to get "isFormField" with "Part" class (servlet 3.0)?

Comment: i cant understand your question ?

Comment: I want know that, how can I know if it's a form field using second solution? (api servlet 3.0)

Comment: what you mean by second solution ?