# JavaMail - Attachment filename not displaying UTF-8 characters correctly

Tags: java

I am trying to send mails that may contain UTF-8 characters in subject, message body and in the attachment file name.

I am able to send UTF-8 characters as a part of Subject as well as Mesage body. However when I am sending an attachment having UTF-8 characters as a attachment file name, it is not displaying it correctly.

So my question is how can I set attachement filename as UTF-8?

Here is part of my code:

```
MimeBodyPart pdfPart = new MimeBodyPart();
pdfPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
pdfPart.setFileName(filename);
mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(pdfPart);
```

Later edit:

I replaced

```
pdfPart.setFileName(filename);
```

with

```
pdfPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(filename, "UTF-8", null));
```

and it is working perfectly. 
Thanks all.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are trying to attach the file ?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

MIME Headers (like `Subject` or `Content-Disposition`) must be mime-encoded, if they contain non-ascii chars.

Encoding is either "`quoted printable`" or "`base64`". I recommend for `quoted-printable`.

See here: [Java: Encode String in quoted-printable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574745/java-encode-string-in-quoted-printable)

Answer (score -1):

maybe help.

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

file.encoding=UTF-8 - This helps to have the Unicode characters in the file.

sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 - This helps to have the Unicode characters as the File name in the file system.