# MimeMessageHelper cyrillic name attachment

Tags: java, email

Good day! Can't find the answer on my problem, so I need a help. I'm using MimeMessage to send e-message with pdf attachment which has cyrillic name. On thunderbird mail client I see attachmen's name as it should be(without any problem), but on outlook attachment's name look's like =UTF-8?4FG54... Attachment is pdf file, can't understand why it's happening, because I see mail's body text and subject on cyrillic on both clients properly.

```
MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
messageHelper.setFrom("myMail@mail.com");
messageHelper.setTo("target@mail.com");
messageHelper.setSubject("Заголовок");
messageHelper.setText("Письмо");
messageHelper.addAttachment("Файл.pdf", new ByteArrayResource(data));
javaMailSender.send(message);
```

message is MimeMessage type

Comment: is this even your programs fault, or does outlook generally fail for that, even if sent from a different client? Maybe this isn't about your code (and would thus be off-topic here)

Comment: MimeUtility.encodeText("Файл.pdf")

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
messageHelper.addAttachment(MimeUtility.encodeText("Файл.pdf", "CP1251", "B"), new ByteArrayResource(attach));
```

it's help for me

or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49596504/8425969

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mimeMessageHelper.setEncodeFilenames(false);
```