# Attachment name containing cyrillic is displayed in encrypted form in gmail

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

An application is developed on spring boot 1.5.15.RELEASE. Used java-mail-api 1.5.6.

**Task**: send a letter on gmail with an attachment with cyrillic name

> Enviroments: dev: Windows 10 Pro, Payara Server 5.183, java 1.8.0_181
>   server: Ubuntu 16.04.4, Payara Server 5.183, java 1.8.0_171

**Send message code**:

```
MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
...
messageHelper.addAttachment("тестовый_файл.pdf", templateProcessorService.processTemplate("template.docx", request, "pdf"));
```

**Problem**:
In a letter sent from the dev environment, the name of the attachment is displayed correctly.
In a letter sent from the server environment, the name of the attachment is displayed as

> =_UTF-8_B_0J7RgtC60YDRi9GC0LjQtV_RgdGH0LXRgtCwX9C00LXQv9C Ln___ ___filename_1=__BkZg==_=

Please, tell me, what could be the reason and how to fix this problem.

Comment: "on gmail" is it to a gmail account?

Comment: yes, sorry for mistakes - google translate

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
messageHelper.addAttachment(MimeUtility.encodeText("тестовый_файл.pdf", "CP1251", "B"), templateProcessorService.processTemplate("template.docx", request, "pdf"));
```

it's help for me

or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49596504/8425969