# Encode image from URL in Base64 in Java

Tags: java, base64, encode

I want to encode and save from an URL images in Base64.
I found several example doing the encoding from a local file but not from an URL.
Is there a possibility to do that?

I tried something like that, but unsuccessfully. Any clue,help?
Thanks for your answer.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String imageUrl = "http://www.avajava.com/images/avajavalogo.jpg";
    String destinationFile = "image.jpg";

    try {           
        // Reading a Image file from file system
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();

        FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(is.toString());
        byte imageData[] = new byte[2048];
        imageInFile.read(imageData);

        // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
        String imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);
        System.out.println("imageDataString : " + imageDataString);




        System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
    }

}

/**
 * Encodes the byte array into base64 string
 *
 * @param imageByteArray - byte array
 * @return String a {@link java.lang.String}
 */
public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageByteArray);
}
```

Comment: `FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(is.toString());` this is wrong, read the API docs, make sure you understand exactly what each line in your code is doing.

Comment: I know this a the wrong part. I took an example wich take a File. But I tried to adapt it with a URL and InputStream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use FileInputStream.

Use something like:

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Also you need to read data in loop until you read all bytes of image.

Answer (score 13):

Try this function by passing image url in parameter.

```
private String getByteArrayFromImageURL(String url) {

    try {
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        baos.flush();
        return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: For multiple downloads, add ucon.setRequestProperty("connection","close");

Answer (score 6):

Following code converts image into the base64 string:

```
public String getBase64EncodedImage(String imageURL) throws IOException {
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(imageURL); 
    InputStream is = url.openStream();  
    byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(is); 
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
}
```

P.S. Above code uses `commons-io` as a dependency.

Answer (score 6):

```
/**
     *
     * @param url - web url
     * @return - Base64 String
     * Method used to Convert URL to Base64 String
     */
    public String convertUrlToBase64(String url) {
        URL newurl;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        String base64 = "";
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            newurl = new URL(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
            base64 = Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return base64;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what this line does?

```
FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(is.toString());
```

First it calls `toString` on an `InputStream` object. That will result in a string that looks something like: `InputStream@23e5aa`. Then it tries to open a file with that name. You don't want to read a file named `InputStream@23e5aa`, so this is totally wrong.

What you want to do instead is read all the bytes in the original `InputStream is` into a byte array. How to do that is explained in the answers to this question:

[Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Finally, I used something like that.`url = new URL(imageUrl);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
      byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                imageDataString = encodeImage(bytes);`