# How to send file using HttpClient when I only have inputstream

Tags: java, post, apache-commons, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to POST a file using `HttpClient`. However, I don't have access to the actual `File` but I have access to its `InputStream`. Is there a way I can still POST the file?

This is what I have done so far:

```
 public void sendFile (InputStream instream) {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8080/myservice/testupload");
    Part[] parts = new Part[] {
            //new FilePart("myFile", file.getName(), file)
    };
    method.setRequestEntity(
    new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, method.getParams()));
    client.executeMethod(method);
 }
```

as you can see, the `FilePart` needs file but I have `InputStream`. How can I POST the input stream as a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [javadoc for FilePart](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/FilePart.html), there is a constructor which accepts [PartSource](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/PartSource.html) instead of File, and there is a subclass of PartSource called [ByteArrayPartSource](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/ByteArrayPartSource.html), which you can construct from `byte[]`; you can obtain this from the `InputStream` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java).