# Problems with getting number of chars in a file

Tags: java, file

I don't understand why the first variant is working and the second is not.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, charsetName));
try {            
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    reader.read(buffer, 0, 4096);
    return new String(buffer);
} finally {
    reader.close();
}

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, charsetName));
try {
    int size = 0;
    int ch=0;
    while ((ch=reader.read())!=-1){
        size++;
    }
    char[] buffer = new char[size];
    reader.read(buffer, 0, size);
    return new String(buffer);
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: In your non-working version, the file pointer is located at the end of the file after the `read` loop. You need to rewind the file to its starting position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedReader`  use a sort of pointer in the file to locate the position from where he should read , this pointer change whenever we call read(*) method. so in your case the second want will read nothing because the pointer has reach the end of the file.

Comment: i got it, but how to get to know the size of the stream without using the first read?

Comment: if you build your input stream from a file then you can get the site by calling `file.length()` . if not then try to convert InputStream to ByteArrayInputStream check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17861016/1250229)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, *both* of your snippets are broken. Your're calling `read` without taking any notice of the return value. There could be more data to be read, and it may very well not have filled the buffer... but you're using the whole buffer anyway.

Next, your second piece of code is reading to the end of the content... and then trying to read *more* content. That's not going to work.

I'd strongly suggest abandoning doing this yourself, and using something like [`Files.toString(File, Charset)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). There's no need to reinvent the wheel here, and if you *did* want to reinvent it, you'd need to change quite a lot of your code. (I'd probably start from scratch...)