# Java - downloading image by bytes downloads a broken image

Tags: java, image, networking

Hello I was curious on how data can be downloaded in java, so I looked through few methods and decided to use `BufferedInputStream`.

Now when I download, I download the file by 1024 bytes burst, and everytime it downloads 1kb I  concat the temp array to the main data array.tH

I use this concat method:

```
public static byte[] concat(byte[] data, byte[] bytes) {
     byte[] result = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length + bytes.length);
     System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, result, data.length, bytes.length);
     return result;
}
```

This is my download process:

```
    URL target = new URL ("http://freshhdwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Image-Art-Gallery.jpg");
    URLConnection t = target.openConnection();
    t.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "NING/1.0");
    t.connect();
    
    BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(t.getInputStream());
    
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int count;
    
    byte[] data = new byte[0];
    
    while ( (count = stream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) != -1) {
        System.out.println(count);
        data = concat(data, bytes);
    }
```

Now after downloading, I convert the bytes array to `BufferedImage` using `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
    InputStream s = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedImage m = ImageIO.read(s);
```

And then I display the result:

```
    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    j.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(m)));
    j.pack();
    j.setVisible(true);
```

Now the result image looks like this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/baec749189c0658e113217749ef92d6b.png))</sub>

As you see, the image looks broken, missing bytes when downloading.
This is the real image:

[img http://freshhdwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Image-Art-Gallery.jpg](http://freshhdwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Image-Art-Gallery.jpg)

What did I do wrong that it displays the image like that?

Comment: your code works me perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each loop iteration, you potentially read less than `bytes.length` bytes. As such, you can't use the full length of the array. You need to use exactly that part that was actually read.

One solution is to use

```
while ((count = stream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) != -1) {
    System.out.println(count); // this should hint at this
    data = concat(data, bytes, count); // use the count
}
```

and

```
public static byte[] concat(byte[] data, byte[] bytes, int count) {
    byte[] result = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length + count);
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, result, data.length, count);
    return result;
}
```

so as to only copy over the bytes you've actually received.

Consider using some of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-in-java). They are probably more efficient or, at least, more readable.