# Java how to read from an InputStream the incomed size?

Tags: java

```
byte[] b = new byte[10000];
len = readerIn.read(b); // InputStream
```

My byte size is 10000, but the `InputStream` size may be lower or higher. Is there a way to read only the size of data that comes into the `InputStream`?

Comment: Are you asking how to read an input stream completely into a byte array of the correct length? Or do you just want to know the size of the stream, without reading it?

Comment: @Duncan yes I want to read the correct size, the exact size, no more or less into the byte array, or any other class that can help me save the readed bytes

Comment: You cannot get the size without loading it.

Comment: Grrrrrr, you edited your comment just as I closed as a duplicate to a different question. The correct duplicate is: [Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1264709). You've earned a down-vote from me, because this is an easily researched topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ByteArrayOutputStream` for this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int reads = is.read();

while(reads != -1){
    baos.write(reads);
    reads = is.read();
}

byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
```

the data array has the proper size and contains all the data of or `InputStream`

Comment: Reading and writing one byte at a time will be very very inefficient, particularly if the incoming stream is not internally buffered.  Much better would be [this answer from the linked duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1264737/592139) which uses bulk read and write via a temporary fixed size buffer.

Answer (score -1):

You can read the totally size of data reading byte by byte by no putting paramenter in read method:

```
len = readerIn.read();
```

You can readstill the end of the stream

```
 while((readerIn.read())!=-1){

     [your code]

 }
```

Comment: if I read it like this, where the data will be putted if there are not byte buffer param?

Comment: This reads one byte, and returns one byte. I don't think it's what you wanted.

Comment: This is completely wrong. This reads one byte from the input stream.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I have not expressed well. I forgot to add the loop

Comment: @RafaRomero one more question, how can I read it without explicitly indicate the size byte[] = new byte[1024], I wished to make it dynamic, but here I have to create this byte array again

Comment: **You code is still wrong**. `len` implies a length is returned, when in fact a byte value from the stream is returned. And you could really do with indicating what `[your code]` is supposed to be. I honestly don't know how this got 3 up-votes - amazing.