# JaxRS ParamConverter for java.io.File

Tags: java, jax-rs, converters

I'm trying to implement FormParam annotation support for a lightweight jax-rs engine. There I want to support `FormParam("") File` type of service implementation with multipart/form-data

According to the jax-rs spec there is a `ParamConverterProvider` and `ParamConverter` interfaces for the conversion purposes. But the method 
accept a string.

```
@Override
public Object fromString(String s) {
     //
}
```

Is it a good approach to use this for File?
If not what should be the better approach. At the moment I don't use any converters for `java.io.File` but just parse as it is.

Comment: `@FormParam` is for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which is only ASCII character, which at the application level is a String. That's why it allows for only String. The param converter is is used for only `@XxxParam` annotations all of which only can contain Strings in there values, e.g. Headers, Query strings, URL form encoded data.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Your question is not very clear as what you want to happen

Comment: If you are trying to actually use multipart, just use the multipart feature that would specific to your JAX-RS implementation. You don't need to try and create your own deserialization. If you just want to accept a single file, you an use `application/octet-stream` as the content-type and you can accept `File`, `InputStream`, or `byte[]` already out of the box

Comment: @peeskillet I'm trying to implement FormParam to support File objects with multipart/form-data requests.

Comment: Why? It's not possible. Even if it was, why would you want to do it yourself? Parsing multipart requests is not an easy task. Every JAX-RS implementation already multipart support. What implementation are you using? Maybe I can direct you to the documentation for that implementation.

Comment: @peeskillet I'm actually trying to provide FormParam support for a own jaxrs engine :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are uploading a file 
Use @FormDataParam

```
@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition
```

See [FileUpload with JaxRs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797650/fileupload-with-jaxrs)