# Unable to get FormDataContentDisposition parameter while uploading file using jax-rs

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, jax-rs

I am trying to upload a file using jar-rs and postman.

```
  @POST  
  @Path("/upload")  
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)  
  public Response uploadFile( @DefaultValue("true") 
            @FormDataParam("enabled") boolean enabled,
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {


        String uploadedFileLocation = "D://uploadedFiles/" + 
                                                fileDetail.getFileName();
        System.out.println(uploadedFileLocation);
}
```

But while excuting webservice I am getting `fileDetail` parameter as *null*.
Why it is *null*?

Comment: You have mapped the same parameter to two variables here i.e uploadedInputStream & fileDetail. `@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
 @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail`

Comment: Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25889454/540195

Comment: In refererence example they have also given same name

Comment: @Amit I have refered same link

Comment: what about your request code? You have to send exact same name "file"
 MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("file", fileContent);

Comment: @Amit I am using postman