# 415 Unsupported Media Type error when uploading file to Webservice through Postman

Tags: web-services, jersey, postman

I have used Jersey Restful API to create a web service and I have the below:

```
@POST
@Path("/process/")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response process(@FormDataParam("upload") InputStream is, @FormDataParam("upload") FormDataContentDisposition formData);
```

I have used the following dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.1-m01</version>
   </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Configuration in Web.xml:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/ws-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

in ws-context.xml, I have this part:

```
<bean id="restManagerService" class="com.rs.service.impl.RestManagerServiceImpl">
        <property name="restRequestService" ref="restRequestService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
    </bean>

    <jaxrs:server id="userManagerREST" address="/rest/v1">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="restManagerService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
            <ref bean='multipartResolver' />
            <bean class="com.rs.exception.ExceptionHandler" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

Now to test this, I am using Postman app to send a Post request. Below is the content from the *code* window:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxxxxxxxxx

------WebKitFormBoundaryxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="test.json"
```

I have already referred to several samples on google, like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/) , [this](https://www.concretepage.com/webservices/upload-file-using-restful-web-services-jax-rs),  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797650/fileupload-with-jax-rs) and I see that I have provided the parameters correctly but I still get 415 Unsupported Media Type error in Postman. I have several other web services in this project which consumes MediaType application/json so the project configuration shouldn't be an issue.

Can somebody please shed some light as to what is wrong here.

UPDATE: Added additional details related to all jersey and WS related dependencies used and important content from the web.xml file

Comment: Three things. 1. What Jersey version are you using? 2. Can you show your dependencies. 3. Can you show you application configuration.

Comment: Jersey-multipart: 1.19.4, jersey-core: 1.19.4. I am doing this in an existing project where several other web services are already working which consume MediaType application/json. If you would need more details apart from these, let me know, I will try to provide

Comment: Please update your post will _all_ the request information. Do not put it in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Updated question with more details, thanks.

Comment: Can you post _all_ dependencies related to Jersey. Also can you post your app configuration (whether it be web.xml or Java config) and what server are you using?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha please see the updated question now

Comment: Not sure what's going on there; You are showing Jersey dependencies, but your configuration is for CXF. What's the deal? Which one are you using? If you are using CXF, then you should use the CXF multipart support, not Jersey's

Answer (score 10):

It could be a problem in Postman, not your code. I had this problem as well.

Try removing `Content-type` header, and make sure you select `form-data` in the `body` tab:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Cdeez Have you tried using a different client to test ?