# writing the uploaded files to disk received using jax rs

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, ibm-rad

Am trying to upload a multipart files using jquery form data and trying to receive the file using jax-rs and need to write the files to disk and am able to recieve the file but how to write to disk?

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response postFormData(@FormParam("thefile") File theFile) {

// how to write the file to disk..

}
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797650/fileupload-with-jax-rs

Comment: i need to save this as pdf itself but it is saving as file @StvnBrkdll