# Upload large data file in JAX-RS Rest API

Tags: java, api, rest, jax-rs, wildfly

I need to send large sized data file to back- end  in chunks and then need to collect it in one orderv in JAX-RS request.

Is there any way to do this by POST request.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: JAX-RS - works with text only data, not binary as image is. So you have to convert your image to BAS464 first, and then send it as the text. See https://gist.github.com/gorlok/656e0f87842796e80203eff3f510ed6a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileUpload with JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797650/fileupload-with-jax-rs)