# RESTEasy: return InputStream in response

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I'm working on a service to PUT and GET InputStream objects based on a key - these can be anything from basic Strings to files.  Here is the PUT method which appears to work just fine:

```
@PUT
@Path("{key}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response addData(
    final @PathParam("key") String key,
    final InputStream data) {
  final Service service =  new Service();
  try {
    service.addData(key, data);
  } finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(data
  }
  return Response.status(204).build();
}
```

Now when I want to get the data (based on a key) I want to return the InputStream which is how the object is stored and retrieved. This is what I have currently:

```
@GET
@Path("/{key}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  public InputStream getData(
    @PathParam("key") String key) {
  // get service and do other stuff ...
  return service.getData(); //This is an InputStream
}
```

When I send a GET, I get a status 200 and a 'Response Does Not Contain Any Data' message ... when I examine the request in Fiddler, it doesn't look like the data is attached. Am I missing something simple here?  Thanks.

Edit: Here are the responses from:

- Advanced Rest Client: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VabeK.jpg
- Fiddler: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1KTc.jpg

It seems like there's nothing attached to the response, but I'm not sure. Is there a good way to test whether or not it's returning the InputStream?

---

Edit2: Interesting. Per peeskillet's suggestion of reading the data to see if it's even there I did this:

```
final String data = IOUtils.toString(stream);
```

This returns `""` when it should be returning `"test"`. Now I'm not super familiar with IOUtils so maybe their `toString(InputStream)` is causing it to be `"test"`, but that would suggest that it's not getting set properly in the service.

My service for getting the InputStream data looks something like this:

```
final InputStream data = getData(_key);
  try {
    if (data == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return object.newBuilder()
      .setKey(_key)
      .setData(data)
      .build();
  } finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(data);
  }
```

Would anything in the service be causing the stream to be read therefore making it non-accessible?

---

Edit3: The problem is in the service when I set the data to be returned. If I remove `IOUtils.closeQuietly(data);` I'm able to get the data back just fine. However this causes issues because I leave an InputStream open... any workaround suggestions?

Comment: Try and read the stream from inside the resource method and return _that_ result instead of the stream. See if it returns anything

Comment: I added more information to my original post...thanks for the suggestion. It would seem I'm pretty clearly doing something wrong in the service layer.

Comment: If you close the stream RESTeasy can't read from it. You could try to close the stream in your resource-method. But I doubt if you'll have real streaming through all your layers anyway.

Comment: I tried wrapping  it in a try/finally block in the resource where the `try` gets the InputStream and returns it and then the `finally` closes the stream, but I get the same results as before. I'm assuming the stream is closed first and then it attempts to return what's not there.

Comment: Have you consider return something else rather than an InputStream, from `getData()` method? Like maybe a `byte[]`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1264756/2587435)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to leaving the InputStream open. However, there was a bug in the version of RestEasy that caused the InputStream to not be closed. The ticket/fix is found here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-741

Answer (score 0):

Returning  an `InputStream` should work unless somebody already read from the stream. You can't read twice from an `InputStream`.

Comment: As far as I can tell the InputStream has not been read at all. This is the response in the Advanced Rest Client (http://i.imgur.com/OfSSAxj.jpg) and here in Fiddler (http://i.imgur.com/DTtkByr.jpg). It seems that there's nothing attached to it, but I'm not sure if there's a good way to verify whether there is or not.