# Providing font in jar in iText7

Tags: itext

In iText7, is it possible to create a PdfFont from a classpath font resource*?

Currently, I save the resource to a temporary folder and use

```
PdfFont font;

public void setFont() {
    font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontProvider.getFont(), PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
}
```

Where FontProvider.getFont() either returns a path to the classpath file for use in the IDE or saves a file to a temporary folder on the host system and returns a path to this.

If possible, I'd like to avoid the step of saving the file to the host system.

(* an open licensed font)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All static `PdfFontFactory::createFont` methods also have an overload that requires a `byte[]` instead of a `String`. So you'll need to find a way to get your resource into a `byte[]`.

From the resource location, you can create an `InputStream`. Then you can use a third-party method to get the bytes from that `InputStream` (e.g.
[Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java)).

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/class/path/URI");
byte[] fontBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is); // from Apache Commons IO
PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontBytes, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

FYI iText will internally use a similar algorithm to convert a resource referenced by a `String` to a `byte[]` for further processing in an `IRandomAccessSource`.