# Byte array to file in java without overwriting,

Tags: java, arrays, fileoutputstream

The code below gets a byte array from an HTTP request and saves it in bytes[], the final data will be saved in message[].

I check to see if it contains a header by converting it to a String[], if I do, I read some information from the header then cut it off by saving the bytes after the header to message[].

I then try to output message[] to file using FileOutputStream and it works slightly, but only saves 10KB of information,one iteration of the while loop, (seems to be overwriting), and if I set the FileOutputStream(file, true) to append the information, it works... once, then the file is just added on to the next time I run it, which isn't what I want.  How do I write to the same file with multiple chunks of bytes through each iteration, but still overwrite the file in completeness if I run the program again?

```
byte bytes[] = new byte[(10*1024)];
            while (dis.read(bytes) > 0)
            {
                //Set all the bytes to the message
                byte message[] = bytes;
                String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

                //Does bytes contain header?
                if (string.contains("\r\n\r\n")){
                    String theByteString[] = string.split("\r\n\r\n");
                    String theHeader = theByteString[0];
                    String[] lmTemp = theHeader.split("Last-Modified: ");
                    String[] lm = lmTemp[1].split("\r\n");
                    String lastModified = lm[0];
                    //Cut off the header and save the rest of the data after it
                    message = theByteString[1].getBytes("UTF-8");

                    //cache
                    hm.put(url, lastModified);
                }

                //Output message[] to file.
                File f = new File(hostName + path);
                f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
                f.createNewFile();
                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                    fos.write(message);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're opening a new `FileOutputStream` on each iteration of the loop. Don't do that. Open it *outside* the loop, then loop and write as you are doing, then close at the end of the loop. (If you use a try-with-resources statement with your `while` loop inside it, that'll be fine.)

That's only part of the problem though - you're also doing *everything else* on each iteration of the loop, including checking for headers. That's going to be a real problem if the byte array you read contains *part* of the set of headers, or indeed *part* of the header separator.

Additionally, as noted by EJP, you're ignoring the return value of `read` apart from using it to tell whether or not you're done. You should *always* use the return value of `read` to know how much of the byte array is actually usable data.

Fundamentally, you either need to read the *whole* response into a byte array to start with - which is easy to do, but potentially inefficient in memory - or accept the fact that you're dealing with a stream, and write more complex code to detect the end of the headers.

Better though, IMO, would be to use an HTTP library which *already* understands all this header processing, so that you don't need to do it yourself. Unless you're writing a low-level HTTP library yourself, you shouldn't be dealing with low-level HTTP details, you should rely on a good library.

Comment: Updated with your suggestions.  I'm just waiting to hear back from EJP on how to set the string.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file ahead of the loop.

NB you need to store the result of `read()` in a variable, and pass that variable to `new String()` as the length. Otherwise you are converting junk in the buffer beyond what was actually read.

Comment: To my new string of bytes?  How would I set the string length?

Comment: @johnstamos: You'd call the string constructor taking it: `new String(bytes, 0, length, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: It is only part of gthe answer and not very usefull, since the processing of headers on every read from inputStream also could result in junk being written to file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with reading the data - you read only part of the response (because at that moment not all data was transfered to you yet) - so obviusly you write only that part.

check this answer for how to read full data from the InputStream:

[Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java)

Comment: `while (dis.read(bytes) > 0)` looks like it's reading all the data to me. It's just reading it in several chunks, and reopening the file for output on each iteration.

Comment: But looking again, there is more to it, I agree.

Comment: @Jon Skeet ok :) sory for the -1, but as you removed your post I can't undo it, I'll upvote next time we met here if you write something usefull - I'am sure you'll do :). Cheers!

Comment: I deleted it to give a more fuller response. Going to undelete soon. (Done now...)