# How to read byte[] of variable size from DataInputStream in Java?

Tags: java, tcp, byte, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I'm working on a TCP server project and I need to transfer a file via a byte[] using a DataOutputStream and a DataInputStream and I've gotten stuck. I'm able to write the byte array to the output stream with no problems, but I was looking at the documentation for the DataInputStream and the method that it seems I would want is read(byte[] b). The issue is that this requires I create a byte[] beforehand, but I don't necessarily know what the size it needs to be so I need some help on how I should go about doing this.

Comment: You don't care. Just use the standard copy loop with a byte array of 8192 or whatever you like.

Comment: Send the size first, then on the receiver, read the size and build the array

Comment: where is your code so that i can help you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache Commons IO [library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). It has a utility class called *IOUtils* which can read an entire input stream into byte array without you having to declare a byte [] beforehand.
For more information look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. All you need is the standard Java copy loop:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or wherever you like > 0
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a library for TCP server and client. You might as well use it.
[GitHub](https://github.com/mihibo5/Java_TCP)

It is not much, but it is simple.