# Redundancy bytes when read file to byte array

Tags: java, android, readfile

Here is some methods to read file to byte array that I use in my android app.

- M1:

```java
   private static byte[] readFileAsBytes(String filePath)
            throws java.io.IOException{   
        FileInputStream fisTargetFile = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        String targetFileStr = IOUtils.toString(fisTargetFile, "UTF-8");
        byte[] inputData =  IOUtils.toByteArray(new StringReader(targetFileStr),"UTF-8");
        return inputData;
}
```

- M2

```java
 private static byte[] readFileAsBytes(String filePath)
            throws java.io.IOException{

        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte inputData[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        inputFile.read(inputData);
        inputFile.close();
        return inputData;
    }
```

I also use method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java?rq=1)
...

But, when I debug, I dectect some redundant bytes, example:

File text: ABCDEF

When debug:
- In M1: `inputData: {-17,-69,-65,65,66,67,68,69,70}`

I know A -> 65, B -> 66,... But Why appear `{-17,-69,-65}`

-In M2: Appear many redundancy than M1.

I have searched, but not find same problem.

Any suggestions for me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: both snippets are wrong.

Comment: Please use hexadecimal notation for byte values. Decimal ones are unreadable.

Comment: `File text: ABCDEF`. Whith which program/app did you make the file? What is the size of the file? 6 or 9? 9 i believe as you have 9 values. But ABCDEF is only 6 characters. Most probably the first three values are a BOM. A byte order mark.

Comment: `-In M2: Appear many redundancy than M1.`??? What are you trying to tell? Dont understand a word of this.  Please post the values when using M2.

Comment: @greenapps, I make app to encrypt/decrypt file with key 128 bit. Above example is short. Actual text key have 16 characters,,... So, with add first three values, it not make 128 bit.  I will read about BOM, Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String targetFileStr = IOUtils.toString(fisTargetFile, "UTF-8");
 byte[] inputData =  IOUtils.toByteArray(new StringReader(targetFileStr),"UTF-8");
```

Do not use intermediate String or StringReader to put the bytes of a file in a byte array.

For instance you cannot put a jpg file in a String as it's no text.

Put the bytes directly in a byte array as you do in the second readFileAsBytes(). That one should work. But you have to check the return value of inputFile.read(inputData); and eventually make a loop.

The three leading bytes are a BOM. A byte order mark. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

```
 The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF
```

Comment: The second one is not guranteed to work (though it often will) since the read call need not read the full array nor the full file.