# Unable to find file after recording audio on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to record my voice, store that to a file, then encode the file to base64 string. So I use the built in recorded using intent like this:

```
    Intent recSound= new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
    startActivityForResult(recSound, RESULT_CAPTURE_AUDIO);
```

The built in audio recorder pops up, and I record my voice, then when I exit the recorded, it goes back to my application calling this function:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == RESULT_CAPTURE_AUDIO)) {
        uri = data.getData();
        File f = new File(uri.getPath());
        try {
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f); << < crashes here
            String b64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.URL_SAFE + Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The URI looks fine and I can even play back the URI, but when I try to read the bytes from the URI converted to a path so that I can convert it to base64, there is an exception thrown telling that the file doesn't exist.

Here is my manifest, and I also get permission at the beginning of the MainActivity:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Here is the exception. The exact code is not shown above because it's complicated so it may not match what you see exactly in the exception.

```
 07-16 19:38:37.854 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/internal/audio/media/37' does not exist
 07-16 19:38:37.864 V/InputMethodManager: focusIn: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{41b3ee08 VFE..... .F...... 0,84-540,922      #7f0d0091 app:id/drawerLayout}
 07-16 19:38:37.864 W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:136)
 07-16 19:38:37.864 W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:994)
 07-16 19:38:37.864 W/System.err:     at com.example.ns.app.MySendImageAsync.doInBackground(MySendImageAsync.java:88)
 07-16 19:38:37.884 W/System.err:     at com.example.ns.app.MySendImageAsync.doInBackground(MySendImageAsync.java:27)
 07-16 19:38:37.894 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 07-16 19:38:37.894 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 07-16 19:38:37.894 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 07-16 19:38:37.904 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 07-16 19:38:37.904 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 07-16 19:38:37.904 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: add file type like `.mp3` or what kind of files you are saving

Comment: thanks, how do i add the file type?

Comment: uri.getPath()+".mp3"

Comment: ok, thanks will try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPath()` on a `Uri` only has meaning if the scheme is `file`. Your scheme is `content`.

Use `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content. This works for both `file` and `content` schemes.

Comment: errr.... how do i read the bytes from an InputStream so i can convert it to base64?

Comment: @PaulMan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java