# What is java.io.Reader transferTo(java.io.Writer) method in Java 10 ? Is there a similar method for InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, reader, java-10

I read the [Java 10 documentation on `java.io.Reader.transferTo(...)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#transferTo(java.io.Writer)) and it says:

> Reads all characters from this reader and writes the characters to the
>   given writer in the order that they are read

The method `transferTo` in  `Reader` would be very useful as currently it is quite verbose to copy data from reader to writer. As we mostly use `InputStream` and `OutputStream` in real life applications, is there a similar method for them?

Comment: Yes.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: Ohh. So it was added in java 9.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681322/2711488 And for the special case of `ByteArrayOutputStream`, there always has been [`writeTo(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#writeTo(java.io.OutputStream))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is such method in `InputStream` since Java 9: [InputStream.transferTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream))

Also, for earlier versions of JDK, there is [`IOUtils.copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-) in [apache-commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library.

Documentation says:

> Copies bytes from an InputStream to an OutputStream

So, it should do the same thing.