# Issue about using PreparedStatement.setBlob on a FileInputStream to a postgres database with Bytea type

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

As the title suggests, im trying to upload a file straight to my postgresql database to the data type Bytea with the .setBlob pstm. However JBDC doesnt like it and gives me the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setBlob(int, InputStream) is not yet implemented.
at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:727)
```

Ive tried the .setBytes() method but im unsure how to use it correctly with the available data.

Here is the code im using for this:

```
private void writeToDB(Connection conn, String fileName, InputStream is, String description) throws SQLException {

    String sql = "Insert into Attachment(Id,File_Name,File_Data,Description) " //
            + " values (?,?,?,?) ";
    PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    Long id = this.getMaxAttachmentId(conn) + 1;
    pstm.setLong(1, id);
    pstm.setString(2, fileName);
    pstm.setBlob(3, is);
    pstm.setString(4, description);
    pstm.executeUpdate();
}
```

Please let me know if there is anything i can do to improve this post, im new to using stackoverflow.

Comment: The [documentation page on storing binary data](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html) has example code that might work for you. Basically, adapted to your example code it's using `pstm.setBinaryStream(is, theLengthOfTheFile)`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I tried this but got the following error: ERROR: column "file_data" is of type bit but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: So, `Attachment.file_data` _isn't_ actually of type `bytea` but instead it's a `bit`. Sounds like your table definition for `Attachment` is wrong, but we can't know for sure because you haven't disclosed it.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I'm really sorry, i had forgotten i remade the table earlier to try another method! Your answer is the solution, now i only need to make it so that i can automatically get the length of the input file.

Also, how do i give you credit for giving the solution? I only see that option in actual replies not in comments.

Comment: No worries. I think you can actually omit the third argument (file length) of `setBinaryStream()`. This will just read the stream until `end-of-file` is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [PostgreSQL tutorial on storing binary data](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html), you can use [`pstm.setBinaryStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream(int,%20java.io.InputStream)) for streaming binary data to the DB. With your example code this would work as follows:

```
private void writeToDB(Connection conn, String fileName, InputStream is, String description) 
    throws SQLException {

    String sql = "Insert into Attachment(Id,File_Name,File_Data,Description) "
            + " values (?,?,?,?)";

    try (PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        Long id = this.getMaxAttachmentId(conn) + 1;
        pstm.setLong(1, id);
        pstm.setString(2, fileName);
        pstm.setBinaryStream(3, is);
        pstm.setString(4, description);
        pstm.executeUpdate();
   }
}
```

Note that I've wrapped the `PreparedStatement` within a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which is the preferred way since Java 7 because it makes sure that JDBC resources are closed properly even if an exception occurs.

If the PostgreSQL JDBC driver doesn't accept `pstm.setBinaryStream()` without an explicit length parameter, you need to pass the `length()` of the `File` object you used for creating the input stream to the method. An another approach is to [read the stream fully into a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java) within the method and use

```
pstm.setBytes(3, myByteArray);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me (Java 8 and PG 9.4)  is converting the InputStream to a bytearray.

```
import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;

// prepare your statement
byte [] binaries =  null;
try {
     binaries = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
} catch (Exception e) {
      ...
}
// bind your parameters
```

Comment: ByteStreams cannot be resolved, and i cannot find a quick way to resolve this.

Comment: This is probably referring to [`ByteStreams`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html) of Guava, which requires you to import and include said library.

Comment: ah, sorry, I thought ByteStreams came directly from java as well, but the import statement says: 
import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;
I'll adapt my answer.