# Write an image from project resources to the byte array

Tags: java, javafx

In the project resource files, I have a default image default_image.png. I need to go to him and translate it into an array of bytes.

```
Image image = new Image("/icons/default_image.png");
URL defaultImageFile = this.getClass().getResource("/icons/default_image.png");
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(defaultImageFile.getPath()));
```

I can take it to the URL as an image, but I can not as a file. How can I refer to this file as an image by URL?

Comment: `new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/default_image.png"))`, alternatively the Method `getResourceAsStream` Then use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java . What is your overall goal, why do you want to have bytes? How do you want to use the image?

Comment: I encode an image using Base64 and write it as a string to a file `String imageAsString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest do the following:

Use [commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), then:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icons/default_image.png")
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

(`try` and `catch` the exceptions.)

**Edit** As of Java 9 no Library needed:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icons/default_image.png")
byte[] bytes = is.readAllBytes();
```

(Again `try` and `catch` the exceptions.)

Comment: It's not necessary to use an external library anymore (assuming java 9+ is used): `try (InputStream is = getClass.getResourceAsStream()) { byte[] bytes = is.readAllBytes(); ... }` ( https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes() )

Comment: Thansk for the hint, in Java 8 it is still necessary to read the bytes, what you show is Java 11. I don't know what the poster of the question uses.

Comment: Just to clarify: The method `readAllBytes` was added in _Java 9_ but the documentation fabian links is for Java 11 (current LTS release as of this comment).