# Java GDK+: Pixbuf image not found

Tags: java, gnome, gdk

Relative to which directory is the file path argument of the `org.gnome.gdk.Pixbuf` constructor? And where should I place the file?

Main.java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main( String... args )
    {
        Gtk.init( args );
        new Example();
        Gtk.main();
    }
}
```

Example.java

```
public class Example
{
    private Pixbuf icon;

    public Example()
    {
        try {
            icon = new Pixbuf( "images/bolt.png" );
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It throws the following exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: images/web.png not found

My directory structure is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(/images/bolt.png)` to get an `InputStream` and use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1264737/4508634) to convert it to a `byte[]`, which you can pass to the Pixbuf constructor.

If you are using Java 9, you can also call `readAllBytes()` on the `InputStream`.

Comment: Thank you. I will check later today and mark your answer as correct if it works.

Comment: The error is gone. The icon is still not displaying, but that would be a whole other question. Thank you!