# Get List<byte[]> from InputStream

Tags: java, arrays, list, inputstream, apache-httpclient-4.x

What I'm trying to do is to get `List<byte[]>` from `InputStream`. I'm sending HTTP request to an API that returns `List<byte[]>` and I want to get that list from the content body.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(endPoint);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(ReqBody));
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContentType());

return response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java

Comment: @Martin'sRun i want to get it as List<byte[]> not byte[]

Comment: `List<byte[]>` means every element in the list is a byte array. How many elements will be in your list? What will the byte array in each element contain?

Comment: @Abra each element will be byte[] of protocol buffer object

Comment: Are you using [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/) ?

Comment: @Abra yes Apache HTTP Client

Comment: `java.io.InputStream` is an abstract class. From the last line of the code you posted, add a call to method `getClass()` to find the actual class. Maybe it's `ObjectInputStream`. In other words, what does `response.getEntity().getContent().getClass()` give you?