# How to download file in Front or Backend

Tags: java, csv, frontend, export-to-csv

I have a Controller returning an "InputStreamResource file". I want that this file appears to the downloads. It isn´t important for me to return this file to the Frontend, but when it will be neccessary I can do this. How can I start a download? Thanks!

This is my Controller with the "InputStreamResource file":

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/csv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getCSV() {
        String filename = "User.csv";
        InputStreamResource file = new InputStreamResource(fileService.load());
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/csv"))
                .body(file);
    }
```

Here I get the csv data in my frontend:

```
 csv() {
    this.userService.getCSV().subscribe(
      {
        next: data =>{
          console.log(data)
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

output:

1,user1

2,user2

3,user3

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the correct headers and return type. The following example returns desired files. The only difference should be the cast InputStream to byte array([Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java)).

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{attachmentId}/attachment", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable Long attachmentId) throws IOException {
    Attachment attachment = attachmentRepository.findById(attachmentId).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
    byte[] file = attachment.getFile();
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + attachment.getName());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(file, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```