How to process large size file of approx 50 GB in Spring Webflux webclient
I am trying to process a large file of around 50 GB, its called master.zip(Its size is around 50 GB) which contains user data
Inside master.zip there are many files named child1.json.gz, child2.json.gz etc
Inside each child file there is a JSON file child1.json
child.json contains multiple minified jsons separated by new line.
Structure of master.zip
master.zip image
Structure of child.json.gz inside master.zip
child.json.gz image
child.json file inside child.json.gz
child.json image
Structure of child.json inside each child.json.gz file
Example
{------JSON Key Value Data ---------}
{------JSON Key Value Data ---------}
{------JSON Key Value Data ---------}
{------JSON Key Value Data ---------}
Now my final end goal is to process each JSON in a line one by one, extract one key out of it called UserId and store those UserIds in my dynamoDb.
The main concern here is that i don't want to load whole 50 Gb file into my memory because it will exhaust my application memory running on ECS Java container.
I tried to process the file chunk wise using **DataBuffer ** but after processing all(4)  json lines from child.json of child1.json.gz file and 2 lines from child2.json.gz
i am getting
java.util.zip.ZipException: unexpected EOF.
Response line -----------------> { userId: 1, name : "devil1" }
Response line -----------------> { userId: 2, name : "devil2" }
Response line -----------------> { userId: 3, name : "devil3" }
Response line -----------------> { userId: 4, name : "devil4" }
Response line -----------------> { userId: 5, name : "devil5" }
Processed 4 lines from GZIP.
Response line -----------------> { userId: 6, name : "angel1" }
Response line -----------------> { userId: 7, name : "angel2" }
java.util.zip.ZipException: unexpected EOF
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:214)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:117)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)

MyService Layer method that call the processLargeZip method of LargeZipProcessor class
public final Mono<ServerResponse> handleRequest(final ServerRequest originalRequest) {
 
   return largeZipProcessor.processLargeZipFile()
            .map( response -> {
                System.out.println("Response line -----------------> " + response);
                return response;
            }).then(ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(" Dump Completed"));
 
 
}

APPROACH - 1
My code for processing master.zip file using DataBuffer
package com.dynamodb.poc.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxSink;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

@Service
public class LargeZipProcessor {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Autowired
    public LargeZipProcessor(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl("s3-url")
                .build();
    }

    public Flux<String> processLargeZipFile() {
        return webClient.get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
                .flatMap(this::processZipBuffer);
    }

    private Flux<String> processZipBuffer(DataBuffer buffer) {
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
            try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(buffer.asInputStream(true))) {
                ZipEntry entry;

                while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    String entryName = entry.getName();
                    if (entryName.endsWith(".gz")) {
                        // Process each .gz file within the ZIP
                        try {
                            processGzipFile(zipInputStream, sink);
                        } finally {
                            zipInputStream.closeEntry(); // Ensure the entry is properly closed
                        }
                    }
                }
                sink.complete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sink.error(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private void processGzipFile(ZipInputStream zipInputStream, FluxSink<String> sink) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(zipInputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String line;
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {  // Getting Error here
                count++;
                String registration = getUserId(line);
                sink.next(registration);
            }
            System.out.println("Processed " + count + " lines from GZIP.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            sink.error(e);
        }
    }

    private String getUserId(String jsonLine) {


        // Write logic to extract userId
        return jsonLine;
    }

}

Here i am getting
java.util.zip.ZipException: unexpected EOF
at this line in code  while ((line = reader.r****eadLine()) != null)
APPROACH - 2
If i change the approach by using byte array class instead of DataBuffer then it works fine  and i am able to process a smaller master file called master2.zip (Same structure as of master.zip) which is some KBs in size
package com.dynamodb.poc.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxSink;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

@Service
public class LargeZipProcessor {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Autowired
    public LargeZipProcessor(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder
                .baseUrl("s3-url")
                .build();
    }

    public Flux<String> processLargeZipFile() {
        return webClient.get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(byte[].class)  // Download the entire file as byte array
                .flatMapMany(this::processZipFile);  // Process the ZIP once downloaded
    }

    private Flux<String> processZipFile(byte[] zipFileData) {
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
            try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipFileData))) {
                ZipEntry entry;

                while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    String entryName = entry.getName();
                    if (entryName.endsWith(".gz")) {
                        // Process each .gz file within the ZIP
                        try {
                            processGzipFile(zipInputStream, sink);
                        } finally {
                            zipInputStream.closeEntry(); // Ensure the entry is properly closed
                        }
                    }
                }
                sink.complete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sink.error(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private void processGzipFile(ZipInputStream zipInputStream, FluxSink<String> sink) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(zipInputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String line;
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                count++;
                String registration = getUserId(line);
                sink.next(registration);
            }
            System.out.println("Processed " + count + " lines from GZIP.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            sink.error(e);
        }
    }

    private String getUserId(String jsonLine) {


        // Write logic to extract userId
        return jsonLine;
    }

}

The only disadvantage of this byte[] approach is that i have to load the fine initially in memory. is there a way to avoid it ?

To confirm, you're not using tar? You're gzip-ing the JSON files directly?

What made you think that if you chop zip file in to chunks those chunks will also be zip files?

I have dowloaded the file in my local system and checked it's content. Also i have updated the structure of master. zip file in my post. the structure is as follows
master.zip ---> multiple child.json.gz ---> val.json

@MatthewFlaschen yes the file i am downloading consists of multiple  gzip files in master.zip file

Please clearly answer: Are you using tar (i.e. are the files .tar.gz)?  If you're not using tar, technically there is no val.json.  If you have child.json.gz, that's just child.json gzipped.

Okay, based on your latest screenshot, it doesn't look like you're using tar.

Yes you are right there is no tar, i have multiple child files like child1.json.gz, child2.json.gz.. which in turn have child1.json, child2.json etc as gzipped file I have updated the post with the pictures of each file and nested level.

I reviewed your code and don't see the problem.  Just for troubleshooting, try gzipInputStream = ...; jsonBytes = gzipInputStream.readAllBytes();  Create a ByteArrayInputStream, then create the BufferedReader from that.

@MatthewFlaschen I am using java 8 and i can't find .readAllBytes() method in gzipInputStream.. shall i use ByteArrayOutputStream and a byte[] buffer to read into it and finally convert it into ByteArrayInputStream ?? One question i have here is one the buffer size. how will i determine that ?

You can copy the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1264737/47773 to a readAllBytesFromInputStream method.

@MatthewFlaschen I tried the above method and still getting the same output and error stacktrace as previous approach

I think @talex is right.  The problem seems to be that .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class) is fragmenting the data into invalid chunks.  See their answer and our comments.  Don't use Flux (and probably not this library).  Just get a direct input stream of the HTTP response.

@MatthewFlaschen Will that be more efficient than my APPROACH - 2 (it's working). also i get the complete inputStream at once..is there a chance of exhausting my application/jvm memory ? since the size is huge

You need use another web client. One that capable to giving you InputStream. Then pass said stream into ZipInputStream.
Simplest client already in JDK
InputStream stream = new URL("").openStream();

I don't recommend to use it though.

DataBuffer has a method called asInputStream(true) , same i am using in my code to convert DataBuffer to InputStream, am i missing something ?? Also what client do you suggest ??

This is not an answer.  It totally ignores the GZIPs nested inside.

Author already know how to deal with nested zip files.

@akhiltomar proble with DataBuffer is that it contains only chunk of zip file. zip files can't be processed that way.

yeah maybe since my second approach withconverting to byte array instead of DataBuffer is working

I see now that talex is right.  I switched my downvote to an upvote.  Everything @akhiltomar does with the ZipInputStream in APPROACH - 1 looks right.  The issue is how you're constructing the ZipInputStream (talex is right that it's getting fragmented).  If you construct it directly from the HTTP response's input stream (forget about Flux), it should work.  Use the HTTP library of your choice (you can pick one listed at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient.html or use the built-in one given here), then get the input stream from the response.

@MatthewFlaschen the reason for using Flux and DataBuffer was to process and release the big file in Chunks.. will directly getting the complete file as InputStream exhaust my JVM/ application memory which runs on aws ecs container with limited memory ? Also can you please check my APPROACH - 2 mentioned in Post which is working for similar structure file but smaller in size

@akhiltomar Using a good HTTP client with an InputStream should not load the whole file into memory at once.  If you don't want to use the simple HTTP client in this answer, try e.g. Eclipse Jetty HTTP Client.  See the "If you want to avoid buffering, you can wait for the response and then stream the content using the InputStreamResponseListener utility class" example at https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/12/programming-guide/client/http.html#content-response .  Once you have InputStream responseContent, you can construct zipInputStream from it.

@MatthewFlaschen okayy let me try it and get back.

URL.openStream(), the built-in Java API given in this answer, is shorthand for openConnection().getInputStream().  For more information, see openConnection() and HttpURLConnection.

As per suggestion from @talex and @MatthewFlaschen I tried Eclipse Jetty client and it seems to be working
Final Code
package com.example.poc

import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.InputStreamResponseListener;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxSink;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.AsyncRequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

@Service
public class HttpClientZipProcessor {

    private final HttpClient httpClient;
   

    public HttpClientZipProcessor() throws Exception {
        SslContextFactory.Client sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Client();
        this.httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);
    }

    public Flux<String> processLargeZipFile() {
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
            InputStreamResponseListener listener = new InputStreamResponseListener();

            try {
                this.httpClient.start();
                List<BufferedReader> readers = new ArrayList<>();
                httpClient
                        .newRequest("s3-url")
                        .send(listener);

                // get response as InputStream
                try (InputStream inputStream = listener.getInputStream();
                     ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)) {

                    ZipEntry entry;
                    while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                        if (entry.getName().endsWith(".gz")) {
                            // Process each .gz file within the ZIP
                            try {
                                processGzipFile(zipInputStream, sink, readers);
                            } finally {
                                zipInputStream.closeEntry(); // Ensure the entry is properly closed
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Closing HttpClient");
                        readers.forEach(reader -> {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                sink.error(e);
                            }
                        });
                        this.httpClient.stop();
                        inputStream.close();
                        zipInputStream.close();
                        entry = null;
                        System.gc();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        sink.error(e);
                    }
                    sink.complete();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sink.error(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private void processGzipFile(ZipInputStream zipInputStream, FluxSink<String> sink, List<BufferedReader> readers) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(zipInputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            readers.add(reader);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sink.next(extractRegistration(line));
            }
            line = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sink.error(e);
        }
    }

    private String extractRegistration(String jsonLine) {
        return jsonLine;  // Extract registration field from the JSON line
    }
    
}

